# Doubt in Construction of Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I cannot understand why we say "The Completeness axiom" (that $\mathbb{R}$ has least upper bound property) when it can be proved from Dedekind's construction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the Least Upper Bound property.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495771/proving-that-mathbbr-satisfies-the-least-upper-bound-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could describe axiomatically $\Bbb R$ as a Dedekind-complete ([A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property)) ordered field ([B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field)) $(R,+,\cdot,<)$. It turns out that for any two such ordered fields $(R,+,\cdot,<)$ and $(R',\oplus,\odot,\prec)$ there is exactly one *homomorphism of fields* $f:(R,+,\cdot)\to (R',\oplus,\odot)$, and that said homomorphism is also an isomorphism of ordered fields.

In that sense, Dedekind completeness is an axiom, although, in any explicit construction of a model of the field of real numbers within set theory, the fact that the "candidate" $\Bbb R$ has the least-upper-bound property is a theorem.

Comment: Expanding on your second paragraph, Dedekind [constructs a **model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Explicit_constructions_of_models) of the reals, not the reals.

Comment: @EricTowers Tahnk you, I edited accordingly (I think).

Comment: Ok! I understand! Thankyou!